# Running Faye in a different environment than Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, faye

I'm trying to setup Rails 4.2.1 and Faye with CSRF protection. I used the guide at http://faye.jcoglan.com/security/csrf.html to get everything working.

**config/csrf_protection.rb**

```
class CsrfProtection
  def incoming(message, request, callback)
    session_token = request.session['_csrf_token']
    message_token = message['ext'] && message['ext'].delete('csrfToken')

    unless session_token == message_token
      message['error'] = '401::Access denied'
    end
    callback.call(message)
  end
end
```

**config/application.rb**

```
config.middleware.insert_after ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore,
                               Faye::RackAdapter,
                               :extensions => [CsrfProtection.new],
                               :mount      => '/live',
                               :timeout    => 25
```

**config/unicorn.rb**

```
worker_processes Integer(ENV["WEB_CONCURRENCY"] || 3)
timeout 15
preload_app true

listen 3000, tcp_nopush: false

stderr_path "log/unicorn.stderr.log"
stdout_path "log/unicorn.stdout.log"

before_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
    Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT'
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

And I start unicorn with:

```
bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb
```

I'm getting the following errors in my log file:

```
Rack::Lint::LintError: Status must be >=100 seen as integer

ThreadError: deadlock; recursive locking
```

The errors are being caused by Faye running in development mode. Is it possible, using this setup, to tell Faye to run in a production environment while letting the rest of my application run in development mode?